# Pass a service instance as a method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I have 2 services

```
MainService
PDFGeneratorService
```

They are scoped

```
 services.AddScoped<IMainService
```

I want to pass `MainService` instance to `PDFGenerator` method in a parameter as a listener:

sample implementation:

```
public interface IFileGeneratorListener {
     Task <int> Notify(int fileId);
}


public class MainService: IMainService, IFileGeneratorListener {
    private readonly IPDFGeneratorService _pDFGeneratorService;

    public MainService(IPDFGeneratorService service) {
        _pDFGeneratorService = service;
    }

    public Task MainTask() {
        _pDFGeneratorService.Generate(1, this);
    }

    public Task<int> FileGeneratedNotification(int fileId) {
        Debug.Writeline($ "file {fileId} was generated");
    }

}

public class PDFGeneratorService: IPDFGeneratorService {
    public void Generate(int fileId, IFileGeneratorListener listener) {
        // generate the file....
        listener.Notify(fileId);
    }
}
```

Is this OK ?

Comment: Looks okay. This is normally the pattern used with Inversion of Control (IoC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing *technically* wrong here. It will compile and "work". However, having a circular dependency like this is a sign of a bad design. It means you're bleeding logic between these two services, so you either are having the services do more than they should or otherwise haven't clearly drawn boundaries between the two contexts.